# Spring @Autowired null problem on weblogic 12c

Tags: spring, autowired

```
Spring's @Autowired value is null. My application is deployed on weblogic 12c.
I have pasted relevant files below along with explanations.


I tried changing to @Component
```

DriverServlet.java:  Set in web.xml. Called by weblogic. Initializes 
  application context.

```
package com.clarksburg.services.configuration;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

public class DriverServlet extends HttpServlet {

       public void init() throws ServletException {
          // Call the AppConfig class to scan all packages
          AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
          System.out.println("Driver Servlet initialized;");
       }

       public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
       }

       public void destroy() {
          // do nothing.
       }
}
```

AppConfig.java:  Does component scanning.

```
package com.clarksburg.services.configuration;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.clarksburg.services" })
public class AppConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AppConfig.class.getName());

    public AppConfig() {
        logger.debug("App Config called by driver");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // Put Other Application configuration here.
}
```

The class 'AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl' implements 'AsynchAQMessageSvc' which was generated using WSDL. It's wired to a OSB proxy on weblogic and get's called whenever the proxy gets a JMS message on a AQ queue.
It's annotated with @Service. I tried to autowire ProcessWsPayload in it but when i use it i get a null pointer exception. Printing it's value is also null.

```
package com.clarksburg.services.messaging;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.clarksburg.services.wsimport.AsynchAQMessageRequestType;
import com.clarksburg.services.wsimport.AsynchAQMessageResponseType;
import com.clarksburg.services.wsimport.AsynchAQMessageSvc;
import com.clarksburg.services.services.ProcessWsPayload;

@Service
@WebService(name = "AsynchAQMessageSvc", targetNamespace = "http://www.clarksburg.com/AsynchAQMessageSvc")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl implements AsynchAQMessageSvc {

    @Autowired
    ProcessWsPayload processWsPayload;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl.class.getName());

    @Override
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetAsynchAQMessage", action = "http://www.clarksburg.com/AsynchAQMessageSvc")
    @WebResult(name = "AsynchAQResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.clarksburg.com/AsynchAQMessageSvc", partName = "response")
    public AsynchAQMessageResponseType getAsynchAQMessage(
        @WebParam(name = "AsynchAQRequest", targetNamespace = "http://www.clarksburg.com/AsynchAQMessageSvc", partName = "request")
        AsynchAQMessageRequestType request) {

        logger.debug("processWsPayload is " +processWsPayload);
        processWsPayload.processWsPayload(request);
    //  new ProcessWsPayload().processWsPayload(request);

        AsynchAQMessageResponseType response = new AsynchAQMessageResponseType();
        response.setServiceResponse("Success");

        return response;
    }
}
```

ProcessWsPayload.java:  It's called (successfully) by 'AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl'. It's annotated as @Component.

```
package com.clarksburg.services.services;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.clarksburg.services.configuration.JDBCConfig;

@Component
public class ProcessWsPayload {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ProcessWsPayload.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    JDBCConfig jdbcConfig;

    /*
     * This method is called by a JMS listener. It is being invoked successfully.
     * However the value of 'jdbcConfig' is null
    */

    public void processWsPayload(wsPayload request) {

        BigInteger wsAuditId = request.getAuditId();

            system.out.println("The value of JDBCConfig is " +jdbcConfig);

            try {
                String SQL = "UPDATE AUDIT_TBL SET ws_descriptions = ? WHERE ws_audit_id = ?";
                JDBCConfig.jdbcTemplate().update(SQL, "Success with soap send", wsAuditId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Failed to update table with success");
                logger.error(e);
            }

}

 I turned on Spring's TRACE logs and have pasted lines pertaining to Autowiring below. 

Spring's relevant autowired logs during deployment:-
```

InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [com.multiplan.services.messaging.AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl]: AutowiredFieldElement for com.multiplan.services.services.ProcessWsPayload com.multiplan.services.messaging.AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl.processWsPayload

InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl': AutowiredFieldElement for com.multiplan.services.services.ProcessWsPayload com.multiplan.services.messaging.AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl.processWsPayload

InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [com.multiplan.services.services.ProcessWsPayload]: AutowiredFieldElement for com.multiplan.services.configuration.JDBCConfig com.multiplan.services.services.ProcessWsPayload.jdbcConfig

InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'processWsPayload': AutowiredFieldElement for com.multiplan.services.configuration.JDBCConfig com.multiplan.services.services.ProcessWsPayload.jdbcConfig

AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'processWsPayload' to bean named 'JDBCConfig'

AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'AsynchAQMessageSvcImpl' to bean named 'processWsPayload'

Comment: How do you use / create new ProcessWsPayload objects?

Comment: I don't create ProcessWsPayload instance anywhere. It's wired to the OSB proxy as a webservice. Whenever a JMS message comes in, OSB proxy calls ProcessWsPayload. OSB proxy has already been created on weblogic server and it works.